# How to get the Inbox for a delegate mailbox that is loaded into the current profile

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto

I have a C# VSTO Outlook addin and I'm trying to support Outlook 2007 and up and I need to get the account names as Recipients for all Stores in the current profile.  Obviously one of the Stores will be the mailbox for the current user, but there could also be delegate mailboxes opened in the current profile and I can't find a way to get the owner's of these delegate mailbox Stores using the Outlook Object Model.

Perhaps a Property Accessor?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop round the stores in your Outlook profile using the [Stores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867405%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property, and check the [ExchangeStoreType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869094%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property value of each [Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862128%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to see if its the type of store you are interested in.

I haven't got a delegate mailbox in my Outlook profile, so I can't say 100% how to get the owner. But hopefully you'll be able to spot a property on the [Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862128%28v=office.15%29.aspx) object that give you the information you need. e.g. the [DisplayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866767%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property.

Here is an example to loop round the Stores in your Outlook profile and check what type of Exchange Store it is.

```
Stores stores = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Stores;

for (int i = 1; i <= stores.Count; i++)
{
    Store store = stores[i];

    switch (store.ExchangeStoreType)
    {
        case OlExchangeStoreType.olAdditionalExchangeMailbox:
            break;
        case OlExchangeStoreType.olExchangeMailbox:
            break;
        case OlExchangeStoreType.olExchangePublicFolder:
            break;
        case OlExchangeStoreType.olNotExchange:
            break;
        case OlExchangeStoreType.olPrimaryExchangeMailbox:
            break;
    }

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(store);
}

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(stores);
```

And if you want to get the Inbox folder, you can use the [GetDefaultFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869924%28v=office.15%29.aspx) method.

```
MAPIFolder inboxFolder = store.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

Comment: The problem is there aren't many useful properties of the store object.  GetDefaultFolder is only available on Outlook 2010 PIA and up

Comment: You can use Outlook Redemption (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) in your VSTO Outlook project. The RDOStore object (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm) has the GetDefaultFolder method and supports Outlook 98, 2000, 2002, 2003, 2007, 2010 and 2013.

Comment: @m_collard, you were correct, you can do it with the DisplayName.  I added an answer below that shows the example.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have just done this using the DisplayName of the delegate account:

```
var app = new OutlookApp();
Stores stores = app.GetNamespace("MAPI").Stores;
MAPIFolder sentFolder = null;
foreach (Store store in stores)
{
    if (store.DisplayName == "DisplayName for your delegate account")
    {
        sentFolder = store.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
    }
}
```

The display name is the name of the delegate account as it is displayed in your Outlook toolbar.